# How can I get into the commandline of a running service?

Tags: systemd

I have a running TeamSpeak Server in a Service.

How can I now execute commands in the runnings service?

Or is this even possible?

Comment: you don't.  If it's running as a daemon service it's not interactive.  Therefore, you can't interact with it if it's executed as a service.

Comment: How? I start my services with service blabla start, then how to interact with them?